# Is there any way to parse through reddit comments and replies through JSON and not through PRAW?

Tags: python, json, reddit

I am trying to parse through reddit comments and the replies to each comment made. However, I am trying to avoid using PRAW. This is the code I have right now to display the titles of each post within a subreddit. But, how do I access the comment field and its replies?

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('http://www.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/new.json?count=500', headers = {'User-agent': 'Chrome'})
r_comments = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments.json')
theJSON = json.loads(r.text)
theJSON_comments = json.loads(r_comments.text)
titles = []
#print(theJSON)
#prints the titles
for child in theJSON['data']['children']:
  titles.append(child['data']['title'])
  #print(child['data']['title'])

for child2 in theJSON_comments['data']['children']:
  print(child2['data'][0])
```

Comment: new.json won't give you a predictable comment structure -- usually the replies are nested in the [data][children] part of the comment, but depending on your params (count=500, in your case) some may or may not be there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using praw and want to get all the comments you can get all of the comments like this:

```
submission = reddit.submission(id=<submission_id>)
submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
all_comments = submission.comments.list()
```

And then `all_comments` is a dict you can use. Not json, but can be saved as a json file.

If you don't want to use praw, you can manually use the [reddit api](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/) with any language you want. However, I have a [blog post](http://danjamrozik.com/blog/reddit_oath2_javascript.html) which says how to set this up in Javascript.

I think PRAW would really help you out here, but otherwise the reddit api is your best bet.